# Use Excel formula in c# (^) symbol

Tags: c#, excel

I was trying to convert this excel code to c#

```
IF(D5=F5,ROUND(((SQRT(F5) +0.0833) ^2),0)
```

and the output for the excel file i'm getting is 19423

but when i use the same code for c#

```
D5 = 19400.25
F5 = 19400.25
string s = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToInt32((Math.Sqrt(F5) + 0.0833)) ^ 2)).ToString();
```

I'm getting the output as 137.
I don't know where I'm going wrong I tried each and everything and got stuck to this thing.Can anyone please help me ?
Thanks is advance.

Comment: `^` is a very different operator in the two languages.

Comment: `^` isn't a power operator in C# - you need to use `Math.Pow(x, y)`.

Comment: Moreover, you don't `round` the same value. In excel you round `(Sqrt(F5) + 0.0833)^2`. In c# you round `Sqrt(F5) + 0.0833`. Be careful with parenthesis

Comment: @bommelding so where am i going wrong?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/xor-operator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `^` symbol doesn't resemble the power function, as in Excel. You can't just translate this one-on-one. The C# `^` symbol does a [bitwise exclusive-OR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/xor-operator).

The actual C# code you should use to translate this function:

```
result = Math.Pow(Math.Sqrt(F5) + 0.0833, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's decompose your c# code:

```
D5 = 19400.25
F5 = 19400.25
string s = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToInt32((Math.Sqrt(F5) + 0.0833)) ^ 2)).ToString();
//                   î                 î               îî__ are closed here ___îî    îî
//                   |                 |______________ is closed here _______________||
//                   |_________________________ is closed here _______________________|
```

So basically, you are converting to `int` the following:

```
Math.Sqrt(F5) + 0.0833 // 139.36[...]
```

This results in a rounding, therefore `139`.

You are then applying `^2` (bitwise exclusive-OR) as stated by Patrick Hofman, which results in `137`.

You then convert this to decimal, and round it, which actually doesn't do much...

---

In Excel, you square `Sqrt(F5) + 0.0833`, this is written like this in c#:

```
Math.Pow(Math.Sqrt(F5)+0.0833,2)
```

Then you round it. Therefore, just wrap this in a `Math.Round`:

```
Math.Round(Math.Pow(Math.Sqrt(F5)+0.0833,2))
```

**But** you only do this if `D5` equals `F5`:

```
D5 == F5 ? Math.Round(Math.Pow(Math.Sqrt(F5)+0.0833,2)) : 0
```

Comment: it's elaborate and awesome.

Answer (score 1):

```
D5 = 19400.25
F5 = 19400.25

double R =  (D5 == F5) ? Math.Pow(Math.Sqrt(F5) + +0.0833, 2) : 0;

String s = Math.Round(R, 0).ToString();
```

But be warned that the condition, `D5 == F5` is already very suspect. Equality for floating point types is easily fooled by rounding.

Comment: Why would you store an `int` in a `double`? Or why would you even use `(int)` in that line?

Comment: Because I hadn't planned on the rounding yet (-:

Answer (score 1):

Probelm 1 : it's different between `Math.Pow` and `^`

origin code logic :

```
var D5 = 19400.25m;
var F5 = 19400.25m;

//Right
var right1 = (decimal) Math.Sqrt((double)F5) + 0.0833m; //139.368080216648
var right2 = Convert.ToInt32(right1); // 139
var right3 = Math.Pow(right2,2) ; //19321 
string rightStr = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(right3)).ToString(); //"19321"

//Wrong
var wrong1 = (decimal)Math.Sqrt((double)F5) + 0.0833m; //139.368080216648
var wrong2 = Convert.ToInt32(wrong1); // 139
var wrong3 = wrong2 ^ 2; //137 
string wrongStr = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(wrong3)).ToString(); //""137""
```

[image]

Probelm 2 : it can be shorter

like `@Patrick Hofman`'s answer
`result = Math.Pow(Math.Sqrt(F5) + 0.0833, 2);`

his answer is great!

Comment: I don't know why the upvotes, this clearly isn't the same calculation than the Excel formula as you don't round the same stuff. This doesn't even return something **close** to Excel's result. That `i2` clearly shouldn't exist

Comment: I just show the data proccess's different between Original logic and Fix logic.

Comment: Your "*right*" is still *wrong* as it doesn't translate the Excel logic

Comment: I fix it @Rafalon ,Thanks